# "How to fix: 'only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices'?

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, data-science, prediction

I'm trying to predict heart disease of patients using liner regression algorithm in machine learning and I have this error(only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices) can anyone please help me to solve it?

```
  import pandas
    import numpy as np
    from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
    from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold
    heart = pandas.read_csv("pc.csv")
    heart.loc[heart["heartpred"]==2,"heartpred"]=1
    heart.loc[heart["heartpred"]==3,"heartpred"]=1
    heart.loc[heart["heartpred"]==4,"heartpred"]=1
    heart["slope"] = heart["slope"].fillna(heart["slope"].median())
    heart["thal"] = heart["thal"].fillna(heart["thal"].median())
    heart["ca"] = heart["ca"].fillna(heart["ca"].median())
    print(heart.describe())
    predictors=["age","sex","cp","trestbps","chol","fbs","restecg","thalach","exang","oldpeak","slope","ca","thal"]
    alg=LinearRegression()
    kf=KFold(heart.shape[0],n_folds=3, random_state=1)
    predictions = []
    for train, test in kf:
        # The predictors we're using the train the algorithm.  
        train_predictors = (heart[predictors].iloc[train,:])
        print(train_predictors)
        # The target we're using to train the algorithm.
        train_target = heart["heartpred"].iloc[train]
        print(train_target)
        # Training the algorithm using the predictors and target.
        alg.fit(train_predictors, train_target)
        # We can now make predictions on the test fold
        test_predictions = alg.predict(heart[predictors].iloc[test,:])
        predictions.append(test_predictions)
    # The predictions are in three separate numpy arrays.  Concatenate them into one.  
    # We concatenate them on axis 0, as they only have one axis.
    predictions = np.concatenate(predictions, axis=0)

    # Map predictions to outcomes (only possible outcomes are 1 and 0)
    predictions[predictions > .5] = 1
    predictions[predictions <=.5] = 0
    i=0.0
    count=0
    for each in heart["heartpred"]:
        if each==predictions[i]:
            count+=1
        i+=1
    accuracy=count/i
    print("Linear Regression Result:-")
    print("Accuracy = ")
    print(accuracy*100)
```

Error shown below:

```
File "C:\Users\Khadeej\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", 
line 705, in runfile execfile(filename, namespace) File "C:\Users\Khadeej\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", 
line 102, in execfile exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace) File "C:/Users/Khadeej/Desktop/Heart-Disease-Prediction-master/linear.py", 
line 39, in <module> if each==predictions[i]: 
IndexError: only integers, slices (:), ellipsis (...), numpy.newaxis (None) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Comment: Can you edit and show the whole error?

Comment: File "C:\Users\Khadeej\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\Khadeej\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Khadeej/Desktop/Heart-Disease-Prediction-master/linear.py", line 39, in <module>
    if each==predictions[i]:

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Comment: "Error in this portion of code" : predictions[predictions > .5] = 1
predictions[predictions <=.5] = 0
i=0.0
count=0
for each in heart["heartpred"]:
    if each==predictions[i]:
        count+=1
    i+=1
accuracy=count/i
print("Linear Regression Result:-")
print("Accuracy = ")
print(accuracy*100)
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<ipython-input-2-c75a200c8276>", line 6, in <module>
    if each==predictions[i]:
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `i=0.0` which means that i is a float. You cannot index a numpy aray with a float number.

```py
    # Map predictions to outcomes (only possible outcomes are 1 and 0)
    predictions[predictions > .5] = 1
    predictions[predictions <=.5] = 0
    # Change to an integer
    i = 0
    count = 0
    for hpred in heart["heartpred"]:
        if hpred == predictions[i]:
            count += 1
        i+=1
    accuracy=count/i
    print("Linear Regression Result:-")
    print("Accuracy = ")
    print(accuracy*100)
```

Comment: Can you please tell me why it is showing this message                   "Name: heartpred, Length: 202, dtype: int64
Linear Regression Result:-
Accuracy = 
100.0
C:\Users\Khadeej\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cross_validation.py:41: DeprecationWarning: This module was deprecated in version 0.18 in favor of the model_selection module into which all the refactored classes and functions are moved. Also note that the interface of the new CV iterators are different from that of this module. This module will be removed in 0.20.
  "This module will be removed in 0.20.", DeprecationWarning)"

Comment: Your program is running fine and this is just a warning. It suggests you to use the ```model_selection``` module but you can keep your code as it is if it is not intended for an important app.